# The current state of UVC LED technology

Tags: led, uv, pricing

I saw this [kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/443292702/quartz-bottle) for a self cleaning water bottle. It's a pretty good idea, and is physically plausible, but I'm a bit skeptical about their UVC LED. UVC LEDs do exist (and they have a picture of a module made by [Rayvio](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/rayvio-corporation/RVXP1-280-SB-074908/1807-1009-ND/7363764)), but they are crazy expensive. On digikey, one of these things is $68 each in qty 4, which blows away their $99 price target. Are there other companies making these cheaper? Is the digikey price a good predictor of volume pricing? The fact that digikey only has 24 in stock seems a bit suspicious. Obviously if they can't get the LEDs at a reasonable price, their kickstarter will fail and they'll basically run off with the money.

Comment: No UV band is going to clean mouthjam off the bottle. I'll stick with my $15 Brita bottle, thanks.

Comment: Obviously there's a lot of hype, but I think the main point is that it sterilises, rather than physically cleaning. I assume that the main thing causing the smell will be the bacterial decomposition, so in theory it should solve that problem.

Comment: If there is a market for it, it will become more commercialized and cheaper. However asking about it is a matter of opinion

Comment: I have heard through the grapevine that at least as of two years ago, UV-C LEDs for sterilization were going for about $10 each at volume.

Comment: I've seen other novel semiconductor devices like that with pretty high prices at low volume at steep discounts at high volume. Because they're a novel device, the manufacturer will likely have to provide a lot of design support, so they need to charge the low-volume customers more to make it worth their while.

Comment: you can get UV LEDs cheap from china on ebay, but none with a high enough freq to effectively disinfect, which needs a wavelength under 300nm to be efficient.

Comment: I think the bottle idea is not very good. UV can kill bacteria, but their decomposition will still stink. The only good will be that an initially clean water in this (clean) bottle might last quite longer without going bad.

Comment: China's Aliexpress sells 280 nm UV LEDs (7.5V 140 mA) for $8.99, https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Deep-UV-LED-280nm-uvled-uv-Sterilizer-Diode-4545-LED-Light-Source-Chip-Beads-Bulb-uv/32762671834.html

Comment: Aliexpress also sells a bottle of about several hundreds of those tiny bleach tablets which will sterilize your water bottle for about $1. Also these don't require batteries. That's a lot more zombie apocalypse friendly.

Comment: I just use the \$2536.5\: \mathring{A}\$ line of mercury for this. Cheap bulbs. Easy to operate. Small. Nil circuit. And if I get Argon mixed in as well, I can use them for the entire visible wavelength calibration of spectrophotometers, too. I wouldn't use an LED that didn't have a demonstrated, significant energy around that line. And I don't know of one, yet. Note that glass won't pass much at all. (Been there, done it, with a glass sorter years ago.) Need fused silica or sapphire enclosures.

Comment: After looking at the datasheet, I'd not bother. That line is essentially flat ZERO out to \$2650\:\mathring{A}\$ and shifts its output significantly longer with temp increase, as well (aka "when it operates".) At the very least under powered operation, imagine that curve shifted *longer* by 10 nm, reduced in power by 50% or more, and then get some research on what's left in terms of effectiveness. Frankly, that thing does NOT look good to me. Everything moves in the wrong direction with temp increase and it's already not so encouraging. I'd wait.

Answer (score 1):

I know one business that supplies medical tool sterilizers using UV-C LEDs.

It may be cost prohibitive for a consumer water bottle compared with chemical alternatives.

For a single UV emitter in the 1 W range the cost is roughly $4/W compared with White LEDs that are $0.25/W

Lite-On Part Numbers with Wxxx in nm. and Vf forward voltage at 0.5A

- W365 4.0V LTPL-C034UVH365  665 mW typ @ 25'C  @ 500mA
- W385 3.7V LTPL-C034UVH385  975 mW typ @ 25'C  @ 500mA
- W405 3.7V LTPL-C034UVH405  1000 mW typ @ 25'C  @ 500mA

Note that the 365 nm emitter is least efficient with 2W power in and 0.66W out but more effective due to higher energy with lower wavelength.

- Wavelength range  Application
- UV-A

  - 230 - 400 nm     Optical sensors and instrumentation
  - 230 - 280 nm     UV ID verification, barcodes
  - 240 - 280 nm     Sterilization of surface areas and water
  - 250 - 405 nm     Forensic and bodily fluid detection and analysis
- UV-B

  - 270 - 300 nm     Protein analysis, drug discovery
  - 300 - 320 nm     Medical light therapy
  - 300 - 365 nm     Polymer and ink printing
  - 375 - 395 nm     Counterfeit detection
- UV-C

  - 390 - 410 nm     Superficial / cosmetic sterilization

**I would have serious doubts on the kickstarters claims as the coverage of light on external surfaces would be small and not easily verifiable.**  Useful bioactive Energy is matter of power* time and attenuated by a sloped bandpass at 264 nm.

For example. UV is also harmful to artwork even if acid-free paper is used. So all museum's must carefully limit the spectrum of UV and  bluish LED light because even this can over a long time cause pigment fading.  ( as told to me by experts in this biz)

[Ref](https://www.digikey.ca/en/articles/techzone/2012/aug/next-generation-uv-led-technology-benefits-industrial-curing-coating)

Comment: 365nm won't be very effective according to https://www.ultravioletpools.com/uv-sun-ultraviolet-light-used-sanitation-systems/ , who say 264nm is ideal

Comment: According to medical research, aka "CIE action spectrum" http://www.temis.nl/uvradiation/info/uvindex.html , the 270 nm UV light is about 5,000 times more efficient in killing bacteria than "soft UV" at ~365 nm. There are many fake devices that use wrong inefficient light.

Comment: It's all relative to wavelength and power above the so called 264nm ideal wavelength.  In terms of energy ( P*t) it's approximately 20,000 times more efficient than boiling (infrared)  so how much attenuation at 365nm ?

Comment: UV-A LEDs exist for R&D but are on the order of $100/mW in volume but is the fastest growing market for LEDs so this will reduce rapidly in 5 yrs.

Comment: I am not sure that IR-boiling process has the same mechanism of breaking protieins and amino-acid bonds as  the 270 nm UV radiation (likely of resonant kind).

Comment: The above categorization seems not to be correct: UV-A is 380–315 nm, UV-B is 315–280 nm, UV-C is 280–100 nm

Answer (score 0):

UVC bottles are a fad. As someone who has closely watched and worked with UVC lights, I have to say that most of these companies are fake. For a UVC light to properly clean water, they must be in close contact for a reasonable amount of time. There can be no dirt to rocks in the water as that will block the UVC rays from reaching the bacteria in the water. For proper sterilization of water in the one minute that most of these companies say, you must have a strong bulb or multiple UVC LEDs in different spots around the water. I think it's a great idea and concept, but it is just not done right.